# Snubber on rectifier diode

Tags: transistors, rectifier, snubber

[image]

It is rare to see a snubber circuit added transistor like that.

On the secondary side, an NPN transistor is paralleled to a snubber capacitor.

- How does it work?
- Is it useful or just little improvement?
- What are the advantages and disadvantages of this snubber compared to an RC snubber without a transistor?

Comment: Wow, what a poorly drawn schematic!    Schematics should be drawn such that the purpose of every system is clear to the reader.  This is spaghetti.   I know you didn't draw it, but this is not good.   Anyhow - can you be more clear?   What transistors are you talking about???

Comment: It's not my circuit I drawn. I Found it in a site. I ask The transistor at secondary transformer.

Comment: Do you mean the K1213????    Those aren't snubbers, they're regulating the DC output  (I think)

Comment: Yes, k1213. I think it's not voltage regulator. No connection to pwm feedback. Pwm input has used by current limiter through CT transformer.

Comment: Maybe "regulator" is too strong a word, but I'm pretty sure that's basically what they're doing.  They work together with the 170V Zener.  More of a "limiter" or "clamp" really.   If the output goes over 170V (approx), the zener starts to conduct. That turns on the transistor, and it turns on "harder" the further over 170 you get.  That will sink power away from the output.  If it drops below 170, they stop conducting.